# Do I need to uninstall vwd 2010 express before installing vs 2010 professional?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have installed vwd 2010 sp1 in my computer. Now I am about to install the professional version. I now wonder if I need to uninstall vwd 2010 express before installing vs 2010 professional?

In fact, when I check my control panel, I see too many programs related to visual studio. The same is true for sql server express 2008R2 that I'd like to replace by Sql Server developer version.

Should I just try to install newer versions, wishing that everything will go well. or, do I need to uninstall older versions first?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same question today, so to be on the safe side, I installed Visual Studio Professional without removing any express versions. I'm running Win 7 home premium, so the express versions are in the Program Files (x86) folder, and the professional files went in the   Program Files folder.  Up to know everything's working well, and I'll probably be asking for help in uninstalling the express version later!

Comment: let me know when you get something